# How to read files stored in cache from other applications?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-file

I am working on a application which download the file from remote server and store the downloaded file's to local cache directory, its working fine.

After that I want to open that same file using ACTION_VIEW intent with another application (e.g open PDF file with an installed PDF viewer, or show some dialog).

Since the cache directory is private, I can not open the file with another application.

Is there any way to do so? Can we make cache directory public to other applications? Or any other method to achieve this, may be sharing the file with `ContentProvider` or something like that?

**NOTE**: I want to store the file in local cache only.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't write thanks, hello, etc. I added code ticks to [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) because it's a class in Android SDK.

Comment: You can start that app's activity from other apps.Or ContentProvider may do that kinds of works.